# Problems printing barcodes / barcode fonts

Tags: fonts, barcode, barcode-printing

Im trying to update a peice of software we have where a barcode is generated by a font then printed out, only the problem is that our barcode scanner cant read a number of the barcodes generated with this font.

I have verified that the font is the problem here through various testing and have been given another EAN-13 (Code 3 of 9) font but no documentation, and I cant seem to find the seperation character that goes in the center of the barcode.

So, my question is firstly does anyone know if an EAN13 barcode needs this seperator character, and secondly does anyone know a good barcode font that works, which is free and if possible has some kind of documentation?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually the code 3 of 9 family needs no separation character.

If your system uses True Type fonts, here's a good 3 of 9 (39) font: http://download.cnet.com/Free-TrueType-Code-39-Barcode-Font/3000-2190_4-10067143.html

Most 3 of 9 fonts require start and end characters, usually `*`. So if you want the barcode to read `1234`, you should have a string `*1234*` and change the entire string to the 39 font.

Comment: Great thanks, the existing system we have uses a seperator and having not written it I was assuming all EAN needed one.

Comment: The * at the beginning and the end what what I needed. 12345 became *12345*.